# Remove Year From Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe, df, with the following column:

```
df['DateofBirth'] =
    1   5/12/2005
    2   20/12/2009
    3   20/11/1991
    4   2/12/1997
```

The elements of the column are date/month/year. I want to make a new DataFrame with years only from this column. I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25146121/edit) but its not working

Comment: why don't you cast it to a proper datetime? `dt= pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'],dayfirst=True)` then you can call `dt.year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str` accessor together with `split`, if column is of string type and its format is constant.

```
>>> df
  DateofBirth
0   5/12/2005
1  20/12/2009
2  20/11/1991
3   2/12/1997
>>> df["DateofBirth"].str.split("/").str[2]
0    2005
1    2009
2    1991
3    1997
Name: DateofBirth, dtype: object
```